# Getting decimal from listbox sentence, then adding that decimal to a variable

Tags: c#

I have a method where I click on a button, and then it gets the sentence inside a listbox in the form of:

```
Person A made an appointment for $45 (for example)
```

The following code is executed when the button is clicked:

```
decimal totalAppointments
private void btnMakeAppointment_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                string selectedListboxSentence;
                selectedListboxSentence= lstAppointments.SelectedItem.ToString();
                totalAppointments += GetPrice(selectedListboxSentence);


}

private decimal GetPrice(string selectedItem)
        {
            return decimal.Parse(selectedItem.Split(" ").Last().Substring(1));
        }
```

And when all is said and done, the amount in dollars gets added to a counter:

```
 "Appointments made for a total of $...."
```

This works fine for round numbers, but when there's a comma involved, the program crashes when trying to add it to the counter of total appointments made. How do I resolve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing real world text is tricky!

Fortunately, the .NET team have implemented handling for many of the common circumstances, such as conventional currency formats. The built-in `decimal.Parse()` has an [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.parse?view=net-5.0#System_Decimal_Parse_System_String_System_Globalization_NumberStyles_) that accepts [NumberStyles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberstyles?view=net-5.0) as the second argument, used like so:

```cs
decimal value = decimal.Parse("$1,200.00", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency)
```

The NumberStyles argument specifies accepted number patterns, such as if currency symbols or group separators are allowed, but not what or where they should be. By default the [current system culture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture) is used, in my case US English, but this can be [overridden](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.parse#System_Decimal_Parse_System_String_System_Globalization_NumberStyles_System_IFormatProvider_) with one of the [IFormatProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iformatprovider) methods:

```cs
var culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ja-JP");
decimal value = decimal.Parse("¥800", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency, culture);
```

You may find that none of the default cultures match what you need, for example if a country recognizes two currencies. For this you can create a custom CultureInfo to support the second currency:

```cs
var culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB");
culture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "€";
decimal value = decimal.Parse("€3.50", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency, culture);
```

Comment: Do you perhaps have a suggestion on how to apply this on my example? I get the error message "input string was not in a correct format"

Comment: I would need to see the input string to know precisely. By that error, something is being passed that doesn't fit the basic currency format. It does pay attention to your system culture, e.g. what characters are valid to group numbers or separate decimal, so if you need to override that, you'll want [one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.parse?view=net-5.0#System_Decimal_Parse_System_String_System_Globalization_NumberStyles_System_IFormatProvider_) of the overrides that takes an IFormatProvider.

Comment: sentence= $"Appointments made for a total of €{CalculateTotalPrice()}.";

private decimal CalculateTotalPrice()
        {
            totalPrice = ((Price) - amount);
            return totalPrice;
        }

Comment: Ah, yep, that would be a culture issue. "€" would only be recognized as valid when providing a culture that accepts it. I'll update the answer with some details around using other culture formats.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Decimal.TryPare

```
if (Decimal.TryParse(lstAppointments.SelectedItem.ToString(), NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out number)) totalAppointments += number;
```